# grep json keys from output stream

Tags: json, regex, bash, grep

For instance I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "mac": "00:11:22:33:44:55",
    "name: "Test123",
    "ssid": "29321",
    "password": "txt",
    "data": {
        "test:": "no",
        "dev": "yes",
        "prod": false
    },
    "signals": [12, 34, 65, 93, 21],
}
```

I'd like to grep a particular JSON key (including subkeys) from data above, but when I `cat` that file or read a JSON file from somewhere else in the output stream, ie `wget` or `curl`.

So far I have tried only this:

```
cat json.txt | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

This returns the `"mac"` key value, grep's it by a pattern, strips all the quotes in the output and it really works flawlessly!

I honestly haven't tried anything regardings JSON keys, since any regular-expression system is not my stronger point and I hope you'll all help me about this.

**NOTE:** I'm very limited on the system where I'll be running this, so the `-P` option is not available.

---

**EDIT:** Actually, we do have root access to devices. They're running on [MIPS platform](https://www.imgtec.com/mips/) and we have no compilers on the system installed. All the apps we can install must be already precompiled, so I doubt I'll find `jq` or `jshon` for these devices.

If there's another tool, that'd be helpful, probably.

---

**EDIT 2:** Issuing command: `akw --version`, we get this response:

```
BusyBox v1.19.‎4 (2017-03-27 19:07:06 EEST) multi-call binary.
```

Comment: Use a json parser like `jq`.

Comment: I would, but I'm very limited on my system where I'd be running this - can't install software, I have a limited version of `grep`, etc.

Comment: It's a system which comes on Wi-Fi broadband equipment from this vendor: https://www.ubnt.com/ - it's based on Linux, runs an old version of PHP 4 (or something), we don't have the root access to it; just a tmp directory where we can store our files, and/or execute available commands.

Comment: Does it have python?

Comment: No. Nothing. Just a very very old version of PHP (around version 4).

Comment: You don't need a compiler *on the system* to compile software for it. People *professionally* building software for these systems don't run compilers on little embedded devices either. Look up [cross compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Comment: Personally, I'm a big fan of [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) as tooling for building system images for arbitrary targets -- though it doesn't need to be a full system image; you could just as easily build a single static executable that way.

Comment: (which is to say -- if you tell buildroot to build static executables for your target platform, and select a kernel that's close enough to being compatible at the syscall layer, you'll be able to just copy out `jq` or `python` or whatever other specific bits you care about from a buildroot image into your existing embedded system -- I'd suggest using a libc, such as musl, that's small enough that the overhead of having it statically linked is at at least somewhat contained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well using `jq` would be the ideal option but you could use `sed` to close

```
sed -n '/ *"keyname": */{ s///; s/ *, *$//; s/"//g; p; }'
```

Comment: With very specific constraints (line-based layout, retrieving scalars only, no awareness of hierarchy, …) this may work, but I suggest stating these constraints _in your answer_.
Perhaps also show how to specify the key name as a variable.